# Firefox Gmail Corrupted Content Error

Tags: firefox, gmail

Just today, all the sudden my Firefox can't access to Gmail. When I try to login to my Gmail, it will shows:

```
Corrupted Content Error 
The site at https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/ has experienced a network protocol violation that cannot be repaired.
The page you are trying to view cannot be shown because an error in the data transmission was detected.
```

I have tried clear all the cache and cookies, and even start my Firefox in safe mode, I am still getting `Corrupted Content Error` message when I login to my Gmail account. However, I am able to access it when I open my Gmail in Firefox private window.

What causes it? How can I fix it? Or I have to switch to Chrome browser in order to use Gmail?

Answer (score 5):

I just found that by using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd> will help to solve the problem.

Comment: Terrific solution. Thank you.

Comment: This has to be done every time the browser is opened, though :/